# How to find frequency of element list in data frame using pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a list and a data frame. I want to find the number of each word in the list (some words in the list are pair) for each "emotions" in the data frame.
Here is my list:

```
[(frozenset({'know'}), 16528),
 (frozenset({'im'}), 39047),
 (frozenset({'feeling'}), 99455),
 (frozenset({'like'}), 49332),
 (frozenset({'feel', 'im'}), 16602),
 (frozenset({'feeling', 'im'}), 23488),
 (frozenset({'feel'}), 202985),
 (frozenset({'feel', 'like'}), 42162),
 (frozenset({'time'}), 17203),
 (frozenset({'really'}), 17247)]
```

and this is my data frame:

```
Unnamed: 0  id  text                                                emotions
0   0   27383   [feel, awful, job, get, position, succeed, hap...   sadness
1   1   110083  [im, alone, feel, awful]    sadness
2   2   140764  [ive, probably, mentioned, really, feel, proud...   joy
3   3   100071  [feeling, little, low, day, back]   sadness
4   4   2837    [beleive, much, sensitive, people, feeling, te...   love
```

Here is the expected output:
6 columns for six existed emotions and the last column is for totall count.
[image]

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: The post has been edited